# WScript to run exe from client PC without any popup windows, silently

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer, hta, wsh

My objective is to launch an **.exe** from client PC, from **Internet Explorer**, without any user interaction needed. I'm deploying in a sandbox environment so the security is not of my concern here.

I've tried using a **.hta** file to run the exe, the codes are as follow:

```
function RunExe(){
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var path = "C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe"
    shell.run(path,2,false);
    window.close();
}
```

The notepad is launched successfully, but with an extra user interaction needed - **User needs to click on Open to launch it**

[image]

I know this sounds funny but this is not acceptable by our users.

Users are expecting the program to execute silently after clicking on the links.

Is there anyway to get rid of this popup box, or any workaround?

Thanks :)

Comment: If there could be a way this would be a security issue. The popup is what protects the user from malicious code and if this is possible it wont be a door to do mischief, it will be a GATE.

Answer (score 1):

In HTA this works for me :

```
<html>
<script>
function RunExe(){
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var path = "C:/Windows/System32/Notepad.exe";
    shell.run(path,2,false);
    window.close();
}
</script>

<input style="width: 170px; height:23px; color: white; background-color: #203040; 
font-family:Book Antiqua;" type="button" Value="RunExe" onClick="RunExe();"
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried your code but the popup window still showed asking "What do you want to do with web_exe.hta?" . As stated in my question, I would like to get rid of that. Thank you

Comment: @HoChiaLeung : You execute this code from a HTA or from Internet Explorer Browser ? and what is the version of your IE Browser ?

Comment: I've executed this code from Internet Explorer browser. I'm using Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: No way if you execute it from IE browser, this comes from security, but if you like to get rid of this popup, you should execute it from HTA.and not from your browser.
Hope that you understand what i mean ?

Comment: yes I understand. I've worked on an ActiveX control as a workaround for this. Thank you :)